# IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type spring boot

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am getting below exception Even I Found  duplicate solutions on stackOverFlow

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class org.homepingo.model.Userprofile
```

I am using spring boot(1.4.5) and I am trying to save userprofile object in user profile table.

**Configuration File:**

```
package org.homepingo.endpoint;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

@Configuration
@PropertySource({"homepingo-datasource.properties","homepingo-endpoint.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"org.homepingo.dao"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "org.homepingo.model" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("org.homepingo")
//@ImportResource({"classpath*:**/springcontext-web-api.xml","classpath*:**/smartdata-sqs-context.xml"})
public class RepositoryConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;



    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }



    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("homepingo.datasource.driverClass"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("homepingo.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("homepingo.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("homepingo.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.homepingo.model" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.getJpaPropertyMap().put("database", "MYSQL");
        vendorAdapter.getJpaPropertyMap().put("databasePlatform",
                environment.getProperty("homepingo.datasource.hibernate.dialect"));
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(loadPersistenceEngineProperties());

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    Properties loadPersistenceEngineProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        // properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                environment.getProperty("homepingo.datasource.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache",
                environment.getProperty("homepingo.datasource.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class",
                "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache",
                environment.getProperty("homepingo.datasource.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"));
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql",
                environment.getProperty("homepingo.datasource.hibernate.show_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

}
```

**Spring application main class:**

```
package org.homepingo.endpoint;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Dao Interface:**

```
package org.homepingo.dao;

import org.homepingo.model.Posttype;
import org.homepingo.model.Userprofile;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

public interface UserProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<Userprofile, Long>{

}
```

**Entity class:**

```
package org.homepingo.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the userprofile database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
//@NamedQuery(name="Userprofile.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Userprofile u")
@Table(name = "userprofile")

public class Userprofile{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_profile_id")
    private Long userProfileId;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="isNumberVisible")
    private byte isNumberVisible;
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="phone")
    private int phone;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "search_view_id", referencedColumnName = "search_view_id")
    private Searchview searchview;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private AuthUser authUser;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_type_id", referencedColumnName = "user_type_id")
    private Usertype usertype;




    public Long getUserProfileId() {
        return this.userProfileId;
    }

    public void setUserProfileId(Long userProfileId) {
        this.userProfileId = userProfileId;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    @Column(name="first_name")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }


    public byte getIsNumberVisible() {
        return this.isNumberVisible;
    }

    public void setIsNumberVisible(byte isNumberVisible) {
        this.isNumberVisible = isNumberVisible;
    }


    @Column(name="last_name")
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    public int getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(int phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Searchview
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Search_view_id")
    public Searchview getSearchview() {
        return this.searchview;
    }

    public void setSearchview(Searchview searchview) {
        this.searchview = searchview;
    }


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AuthUser
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    public AuthUser getAuthUser() {
        return this.authUser;
    }

    public void setAuthUser(AuthUser authUser) {
        this.authUser = authUser;
    }


    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Usertype
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_type_Id")
    public Usertype getUsertype() {
        return this.usertype;
    }

    public void setUsertype(Usertype usertype) {
        this.usertype = usertype;
    }

}
```

**Service Class:**

```
package org.homepingo.service.Impl;

import org.homepingo.dao.UserProfileRepository;
import org.homepingo.model.Posttype;
import org.homepingo.model.Userprofile;
import org.homepingo.service.UserProfileService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service("userProfileService")
public class UserProfileServiceImpl implements UserProfileService{

    @Autowired
    UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;
    @Override
    public Userprofile processProfileToPost(Userprofile userprofile) throws Exception {
        userProfileRepository.save(userprofile);
        return userprofile;
    }

}
```

From past 5 days I am stuck with this exception even though I followed every possible solution found on the internet but none had been worked.Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong with this code?

Comment: Did you try to change the Table and the Entity Name? In some DBs, UserProfle is a reserved word. Did you also check if your relation  (AuthUser, SearchView and UseType) are correctly marked as @Entity?

Comment: @JoséMendes I tried both the options but still it is not working

Comment: @JoséMendes I had generated entities with JPA project but I moved all generated entity classes to module and I deleted the JPA project.I mean I had used JPA project for auto entity generation which saved me some time to write same entity classes from scratch.

Comment: Can you adding @ComponentScan("org.homepingo") on your main class. 
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("org.homepingo")
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Comment: Try move the main application class from package `org.homepingo.endpoint` to `org.homepingo`.

Comment: @PraneethRamesh I tried it but still its not working

Comment: @Alex tried to change the package name but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think ignorance its the best option for this question.It was a silly mistake that I was doing instead of

```
 entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.homepingo.model" });
```

I had written

```
   entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.homepingo.model" });
```

Sorry to SO community for wasting their time.